# Is the Ubuntu Application Review Board dead?

Tags: application-development

Personally, I haven't had a response from either the mailing list or replies on myApps for well over three months. And with the last update on the ARB trello board being from September 16th, I have to wonder if there is any progress being made for anyone?

Answer (score 9):

The Ubuntu App Review board is certainly not dead/scrapped by any stretch of imagination. Its just that we are undergoing a transition period in forming new ARB with new members, Our processes have slowed down a bit and there is a low volume on the mailing list. So Kindly bear with us as we are in a transition process.

Regards

Bhavani

On behalf of the ARB

Comment: In addition to what Bhavani has mentioned, the whole process by which developers upload their apps for inclusion into the software center is being looked into and addressed. You can see the process being formed on this Ubuntu [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppDevUploadProcess).
 
It contains a ton of information and **it's not finalized**, but you can see that they are working on trying to make the whole process faster and easier on all parties.

Comment: Love the spec after a first read.  My only concern is seeing the To Do list at the end. Is Canonical helping at all with this (besides supporting a few key community people)? To really make Ubuntu a dynamic and attractive OS, they need to make this easier for developers to get apps into the software center people might want.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Bhavani and John. I agree with Ian, too. I'm not really an ubuntu developer, I don't even use the OS myself. To see a new version of the distro to come out before my application can even be published while receiving no feedback is disheartening and unprofessional. I'd love to see the ARB really be a part of Canonical and well supported. Hopefully it's going that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at the mailing list archives, it seems like they are responding to people there. And some of the responses are in regards to how long things take. They are swamped right now it seems.

Comment: Yeah, I did read through the mailing list back through when my application was submitted to check for activity, and because of that low activity and the zero responses I have personally received in the past few months that begged me to ask.